# How can I convert the string containing jibrish/black diamonds to hebrew?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the code I'm trying but none of that worked not the 1255 and not the 862:

```
Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(862);//"Windows-1255");
string name = anchor.InnerText;
byte[] latinBytes = latinEncoding.GetBytes(name);

string hebrewString = hebrewEncoding.GetString(latinBytes);
```

Maybe the problem is that it's not latin in the source what I see in the variable name is: `����� �����` instead hebrew letters.

This is the complete method I'm using:

```
private void parseIds(string html)
{
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

    var anchor = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();

    if (anchor != null)
    {
        Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
        Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(862);//"Windows-1255");
        string name = anchor.InnerText;
        byte[] latinBytes = latinEncoding.GetBytes(name);

        string hebrewString = hebrewEncoding.GetString(latinBytes);

        string href = anchor.Attributes["href"].Value;

        Uri uri;

        if (Uri.TryCreate(href, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
        {
           if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
              uri = new Uri(new Uri("http://www.google.com/"), uri);

           var queryKeyValues = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
           string forumId = queryKeyValues["forumId"];
         }
     }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling it in the constructor:

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.DownloadFile("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/forumslistnew.asp", @"c:\testhtml\mainforums.html");
webclient.Dispose();

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\testhtml\mainforums.html");

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("href") && line.Contains("forumId=") && !wholeids.Contains(line))
    {
        parseIds(line);                    
    }
}
```

Where then should I do the encoding to hebrew ?

I tried to use:

```
webclient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Once before the `webclient.DownloadFile` and once after this line but it didn't change anything.

Comment: If you see those symbols its already too late, its been encoded wrong on *displaying* the text in the first place.

Comment: Indeed - don't try to "convert" a string from one encoding to another: apply the correct encoding when first converting from binary data to text.

Comment: I strongly suggest you install a font that shows unicode characters, such as Microsoft's Arial Unicode MS:  https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1081 It will make it easier to determine if the decoded string is actually gibberish, or just glyphs that your font can't display.

Comment: I checked the page view-source and i see on the top that the encoding is: windows1255 so i did: webclient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255"); but it didn't change anything. Maybe i'm not doing it right with the webclient encoding ?

Comment: Here: view-source:http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/forumslistnew.asp almost on the top you can see: charset=windows-1255'

Comment: This is working: string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\testhtml\mainforums.html",Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255"));